# Jenkins Pipeline Expected a Step for Variables & Loop

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Need help in getting the job status.

I tried the below code, but it is throwing

> WorkflowScript: 9: Expected a step @ line 9, column 1. def Status = build job: 'Job Regression'

Sample Script:

````
Pipeline{
agent
stages {

stage('Stg1') {

steps{

Script{

def Status = build job: 'Job Regression'

int build1=0

while(build1==0){

def BStatus = build job: 'JobB', propagate: false

if(BStatus == 'Success'){

build1=0

}```

Thanks in Advance
````

Answer (score 1):

A few things here.

1. Perhaps it got lost in the formatting, but please indent your code properly - it will help you, and others, immensely in the future.
2. Jenkins DSL syntax almost always uses camelCase, and you haven't named some things properly. So your pipeline won't parse correctly the way you've entered it here.

   1. `Pipeline` must be `pipeline`
   2. `Script` must be `script`
3. The `agent` declarative requires an argument. `agent any` works in most cases, or you can specify labels or types, eg `agent { label 'Windows' }`
4. Also maybe lost in formatting, but you must close your braces.

When I fixed these minor issues, it looked like this, and passed validation using the VSCode Jenkins validator:

```
pipeline{
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Stg1') {
      steps{
        script{
          def Status = build job: 'Job Regression'
          int build1=0
          while(build1==0){
            def BStatus = build job: 'JobB', propagate: false
            if(BStatus == 'Success'){
              build1=0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Without knowing more about the problem you're coding for, it's hard to say if your actual script here is a good solution or not. What exactly are you trying to do? On the surface, it seems like it could go on forever? You might want to put a timeout on it.

A good place to start looking at your options is https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/ - the whole "book" is worth a read.